# Unable to import javax.jws.webservice for @WebService annotation

Tags: java, web-services, import, jax-ws

I am working on Eclipse IDE and creating a web-service program. IDE gives an error while importing
`import javax.jws.WebService;`
`import javax.jws.WebMethod;`
error shows the import javax.jws can not be resolved

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;

@WebService
public class Hello {
    private final String message = "Hello, ";

    public Hello() {
    }

    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return message + name + ".";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your pom.xml  if it is a maven project, and what java version you are using?

Comment: Problem was resolved by switching from java 11 to  JDK 1.8, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check that your project has appropriate JDK.

Right click on the project --> Properties --> Compiler

I created your file in Java8, and it worked.

[image]

Comment: My problem was resolved by switching from java 11 to  JDK 1.8, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

in the pom.xml file add

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `javax.jws-api` artifact instead and it will solve your problem. Below is the gradle implementation:

```
implementation 'javax.jws:javax.jws-api:1.1'
```

Check the version and use the latest.

It is not recommended to downgrade the Java version just to fix the issue.